# Absolutely bizarre appendTo problem in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The following code works great in almost everything (variable names changed):

```
this.$something.appendTo($container);
```

But in IE8, it was just... not doing the append. No error. No warning. Not a whimper. Through sheer luck, we found something that worked for no discernable reason:

```
$('<div class="hideme">ihateIE</div>').appendTo($('body')).remove();
this.$something.appendTo($container);
```

It's not a timing issue - there's no setTimeout involved and all the variables are either created right then or have been around for a while. And it works no matter what you append, no matter where you append it to, *as long as you append SOMETHING to SOMETHING.*

Why, why, why, why, why? I hate leaving this hack in my code.

Comment: Why'd you change the variable names?

Comment: jsfiddle.net would be a start..

Comment: @mplungjan good idea, I'll throw one up when I get a chance, if I can get it to reproduce outside of the application.

Comment: Need more detail, but if I had to guess, there's probably something invalid about the document in the first place (like no body tag, or malformed html, quirks mode due to no doctype, etc).